# How to reconnect to a DDE server

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dde

How to reconnect to a DDE server?

The following code gives me 0x4006 error constantly which, accroding to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms648755(v=vs.85).aspx), means `DMLERR_INVALIDPARAMETER`.

```
HCONV g_conv;

void dde_server_reconnect(HCONV hconv)
{
  while (true)
  {
    if (g_conv = DdeReconnect(hconv))
    {
      std::cout << "Reconnect success!" << std::endl;
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      std::cerr << "Unable to reconnect. Error: " << DdeGetLastError(g_id_inst) << std::endl;
    }

    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
  }
}

HDDEDATA CALLBACK dde_callback(
  UINT uType,
  UINT uFmt,
  HCONV hconv,
  HSZ hsz1,
  HSZ hsz2,
  HDDEDATA hdata,
  DWORD dwData1,
  DWORD dwData2)
{
  switch (uType)
  {
  case XTYP_ADVDATA:
  {
    process_data(hdata);
    return (HDDEDATA)DDE_FACK;
  }

  case XTYP_DISCONNECT:
  {
    auto reconnect_th = boost::thread(dde_server_reconnect, hconv);
    reconnect_th.detach();
  }
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Where is the code failing? What is `hconv` passed to `dde_server_reconnect`? Are you dispatching messages on the calling thread? Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The information provided is not enough to answer your question.

Comment: @IInspectable "Where is the code failing?" -- it fails on the `DdeReconnect` function call (this function returns 0L and `DdeGetLastError` says that this is a 0x4006 error). "What is hconv passed to dde_server_reconnect?" -- `hconv` which is passed to the `dde_server_reconnect` function came directly from the `dde_callback` callback. "Are you dispatching messages on the calling thread?" -- in case of `XTYP_DISCONNECT` event I create separate thread and try to reconnect there

Comment: Don't answer in comments. Update your question instead. Passing the *hconv* handle to another thread is dubious. I would expect the handle to become invalid once `dde_callback` returns. This can happen before, after, or in between executing `dde_server_reconnect`.

Comment: @IInspectable I already tried to reconnect in the callback's thread -- I got a 0x400a error (`DMLERR_NO_CONV_ESTABLISHED` -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms648755(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: So you know, that the server has terminated the conversation, and the handle can no longer be used.

Comment: @IInspectable What can I do then to establich connect to this server again?